# How can I send response from a controller method without returning from the method itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a method in my ASP.net core controller which is sending response back on returning.
How I can send multiple responses back without returning from the method.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetWalkByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var walk = await walkRepository.GetWalkByIdAsync(id);
            if(walk == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var walkResponse = mapper.Map<WalkResponse>(walk);
        //////I want to send some additional responses back from here in the function//////
            return Ok(walkResponse);
        }
        catch
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Sorry server down");
        }
    }
```

I am expecting to send additional responses before line "return Ok(walkResponse)"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you specify in detail for *expecting to send additional responses*? For different scenario? Multiple data? In API action, there is only one response to be returned. If you want to return *multiple data*, you can only achieve with combine all data into one object/array and return.

Comment: HTTP request the connection closes after the response.  You cannot send multiple requests on the same connection.  You response is an object of type IActionResult (an actual class/model).  You can create a list object List<My Type> and then add each response to the list.

Comment: `"I am expecting to send additional responses before line "return Ok(walkResponse)"` This is `http response` any statement doesn't work in practice. One method should have one final return statement you can bind many data together in single response but sending multiple response within one request is not valild or accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send multiple returns or responses at once. Instead, Package your target responses as one object package then perform necessary steps at response receiving end to process your responses accordingly.